# In which module i can find Python `Table` and Mapper

Tags: python, data-structures

I am following this examaple

[Creating MySql Table from a python list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914365/creating-mysql-table-from-a-python-list)

and he uses this

```
>>> column_names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
>>> columns = (Column(name, Integer) for name in column_names)
>>> table = Table('data', metadata, Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), *columns)
>>> class Data(object):
...:     def __init__(self, *args):
...:         for name, arg in zip(column_names, args):
...:             setattr(self, name, arg)
...:             
...:
>>> mapper(Data, table)
<<< <Mapper at 0x1026e9910; Data>
>>> data = Data(1, 2, 3)
>>> [x for x in dir(data) if x.startswith('col')] # see if all of our columns are there
<<< ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'] 
>>> data.col3 # great!
<<< 3
```

I am not able to find `Column , Table and mapper` functions where are they defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These classes are not part of the standard Python library.

Look at the [sqlalchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) database libraries.